# Most carefull way to concatenate strings in C

Tags: c, string, csv, printf, sd-card

My firmware in one cycle per 10 second is moving string to the output (csv file on SD card). The problem is that string sometimes in non-deterministic way is changing adding values that shouldn't be there or put space in the middle. Is this related to sprintf function or dynamic allocated memory for that string?

```
void archPolling()
{

    double archCountVal[200];
    float archDataVal[100];
    char *FilStringMeas = malloc(sizeof(char) * 2048);
    char *FilArchive = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4096);
    vArchEvent eventArch = STATE_POLLING;
    unsigned char CiphCRC[5];
    FIL FilData;
    UINT bw;
    int queueSize = 0;

    if ( xSemaphoreTake( MutexMeasurment, 200 ) == pdTRUE)
    {
        eventArch = STATE_COLLECT;
    }

    if (eventArch == STATE_COLLECT)
    {

        while (uxQueueMessagesWaiting(xDataQueue) > 0)
        {
            xQueueReceive(xDataQueue, &archDataVal[queueSize], 0);
            queueSize++;
        }
        xSemaphoreGive(MutexMeasurment);

        if (queueSize > 0 && timerFlag == 1)
            eventArch = STATE_FORM;
        else
            eventArch = STATE_POLLING;
    }

    if (eventArch == STATE_FORM)
    {
        //portENTER_CRITICAL();
        HAL_RTC_GetTime(&RtcHandle, &RTCTimeArch, FORMAT_BIN);
        HAL_RTC_GetDate(&RtcHandle, &RTCDateArch, FORMAT_BIN);
        sprintf(FilArchive, "%02d-%02d-%02d,%02d:%02d:%02d,1", RTCDateArch.Date, RTCDateArch.Month, RTCDateArch.Year, RTCTimeArch.Hours, RTCTimeArch.Minutes, RTCTimeArch.Seconds);
        sprintf(FilStringMeas, ",");
        for (int i = 0; i < queueSize; i++)
        {
            sprintf(FilStringMeas, "%s%f,", FilStringMeas, archDataVal[i]);
        }

        strcat(FilArchive, FilStringMeas);
        archCRC((BYTE *) FilArchive, strlen(FilArchive), CiphCRC);
        strcat(FilArchive, (char *) CiphCRC);
        strcat(FilArchive, "\n");
        //portEXIT_CRITICAL();
        eventArch = STATE_SYNC;
    }

    if (eventArch == STATE_SYNC)
    {
        f_open(&FilData, "0:55AD001.csv", FA_OPEN_EXISTING | FA_WRITE);
        f_lseek(&FilData, f_size(&FilData));
        f_write(&FilData, FilArchive, strlen(FilArchive) * sizeof(char), &bw);
        f_close(&FilData);
        timerFlag = 0;
        eventArch = STATE_POLLING;
    }

    free(FilStringMeas);
    free(FilArchive);
}
```

Edit: example of wrong output

```
0,0,1,3.512586,42.960911,,46.487427,24.501009,1.512586,27.498940,40.960911,36.598400,11.039062,9.401555,25.498940,42.487427,20.501009,7.512586,17.401556,36.960911,32.598400,7.039061,5.512586,31.498940,48.487427,16.501009,5.039061,13.401555,29.498940,46.487427,24.501009,1.512586,27.498940,44.487427,36.598400,11.039062,9.401555,38.960911,42.487427,20.501009,7.512586,33.498940,36.960911,32.598400,7.039061,15.401555,31.498940,48.487427,16.501009,3.512586,13.401555,42.960911,38.598400,3.039061,1.512586,27.498940,44.487427,22.501009,11.09062,AAAA

0,0,1,34.471630,6.303817,15,15.528328,45.382984,32.471630,6.617044,4.303817,29.472881,47.696175,16.527170,4.617044,11.528328,41.382984,38.471630,24.527170,0.303817,25.472881,43.696175,36.471630,10.617044,17.528328,37.382984,41.696175,20.527170,8.617044,15.528328,45.382984,32.471630,6.617044,13.528328,29.472881,47.696175,16.527170,2.303817,11.528328,41.382984,38.471630,12.617044,0.303817,25.472881,43.696175,22.527170,10.617044,17.528328,37.382984,34.471630,20.527170,6.303817,31.472881,39.696175,32.471630,6.617044,13.528328,43.382984,496175,AAAA
```

Comment: May it be that the output is too long and doesn't fit into the allocated buffer?

Comment: Probably not, because it's 600 bytes information in one cycle. Firstly I thougth it's problem with RTC, but changing it to constant values didn't changed anything.

Comment: `sprintf(FilStringMeas, "%s%f,", FilStringMeas, archDataVal[i]);`  -- I wouldn't recommend passing the output buffer to sprintf as an input parameter. A C pedant may be able to correct me, but I suspect you get undefined results if you do this, and that might account for the trouble you are having. sprintf into a temporary buffer, or better still, use snprintf and be explicit about the buffer size.

Comment: @JackWhitham you are perfectly right, `[v]s[n]printf()` must not be supplied its own output buffer as an input; the behavior is explicitly marked as undefined in this case.

Comment: sprintf(buf+strlen(buf), "%f", f) is your friend.

Comment: The `*printf` functions return the length of the resolved format string, so appending further formatted data to a string could be achieved by something like `n += sprintf(str + n, "...");`. The length information can also be used to guard against bufer overflows.

Comment: @MOehm this one is actually the acceptable answer to the question.

Comment: Is the content of `CiphCRC` `0`-terminated after `archCRC` returned?

Comment: From Linux' `man sprintf`: "*C99 and POSIX.1-2001 specify that the results are undefined if a call to sprintf(), snprintf(),  vsprintf(),  or  vsnprintf()  would
       cause  copying  to take place between objects that overlap.*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue Jack Whitman pointed out is the cause for your spurious output: You shouldn't pass the string to print to as an argument to `sprintf`. Another potential risk is a buffer overflow, which `sprintf` and `strcat` don't guard against. (Well, *can't* guard against, because they don't know how large a buffer is.)

You build a single string and then append it to a file. One solution to your problem would be not to create the intermediary string, but to append the partial formatted strings to the file directly.

Another solution is to keep track of the number of characters written. This information is returned by all variantes of `printf`, unless an error occurred, which is signalled by `-1`. Appending to the string then works more or less like:

```
size_t n = 0;

n += sprintf(str + n, ...);
n += sprintf(str + n, ...);
```

If you use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`, you could also guard against buffer overflow.

That is a bit cumbersome. The problem of the `s*printf` functions is that they always fill the string from the start and overwrites the data on subsequent calls to the same output buffer, which is a bit unintuitive, given that `fprintf` appnds to to file and doesn't overwrite anything written to the same output file earlier.

If you have more cases where you want to build a string from succesive calls to formatted printing routines, you could write a small framework. The example below creates an "appender" from a fixed-sized `char` buffer and successively fills it. The result may be truncated to prevent overflow, but will always yield a null-terminated string unless `rem` is 0:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>      // needed for va_list

struct appender {
    char *str;           // original buffer
    size_t rem;          // remaining space
    size_t n;            // (potential) characters written
};

int appprintf(struct appender *app, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    char *p = app->rem ? app->str + app->n : NULL;
    int n;

    va_start(args, fmt);
    n = vsnprintf(p, app->rem, fmt, args);
    app->rem = (n < app->rem) ? app->rem - n : 0;
    app->n += n;
    va_end(args);

    return n;
}

int main()
{
    char buffer[64];
    struct appender app = { buffer, sizeof(buffer) };
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        appprintf(&app, " %d", i);
    }

    puts(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see you use `sprintf(dest, "%s...", dest, ...);` to concatenate your strings. I've just read again manpage for sprintf, and if it is not explicitely forbidden, it not explicitely allowed.

As far as I am concerned, I would **never** do that. Even if it works, you ask `printf` machinery to explicitely copy a (longer and longer) string to itself.

Instead of :

```
    sprintf(FilArchive, "%02d-%02d-%02d,%02d:%02d:%02d,1", RTCDateArch.Date, RTCDateArch.Month, RTCDateArch.Year, RTCTimeArch.Hours, RTCTimeArch.Minutes, RTCTimeArch.Seconds);
    sprintf(FilStringMeas, ",");
    for (int i = 0; i < queueSize; i++)
    {
        sprintf(FilStringMeas, "%s%f,", FilStringMeas, archDataVal[i]);
    }
    strcat(FilArchive, FilStringMeas);
```

I would do

```
    sprintf(FilArchive, "%02d-%02d-%02d,%02d:%02d:%02d,1", RTCDateArch.Date, RTCDateArch.Month, RTCDateArch.Year, RTCTimeArch.Hours, RTCTimeArch.Minutes, RTCTimeArch.Seconds);
    strcat(FilArchive, ",");
    for (int i = 0; i < queueSize; i++)
    {
        sprintf(FilStringMeas, %f,", archDataVal[i]);
        strcat(FilArchive, FilStringMeas);
    }
```

and I would test for buffer size.

Comment: Copy is almost as "cheap" as read, so strcat-based solution (being valid) will probably not be much more efficient. For speed, you have to track and advance current write position by hand.

Comment: Thanks for help. I changed it in code, but it didn't solve my problem with unwanted spaces and values.

Comment: @user3125367 : you are right, and I had even thought about that but I was too lazy to implement it. But in a real use case, it is certainly how it should be done.