# all calls of printf write the argument string to one character array

Tags: c, printf

How can I modilfy my C code such that all calls of printf write the argument string to one big character Array?

Comment: What does the link in your question mean?

Comment: At the end of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966116/most-carefull-way-to-concatenate-strings-in-c/29967657#29967657) to another question, I show a fixed-size buffer that can be filled with successive `printf`-like calls and that is protected against overflow, which might be useful.

Comment: @ Yu Hao: I have just added the source file.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can achieve this:

1. The less generic - use `sprintf` with a running pointer to the next character position
2. The more generic: Use `fprintf` with variable file pointer. It can be `stdout` for the regular IO, or a stream opened with `fmemopen`. See about [memory streams](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_228.html) in GNU C library.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like:

```
char buf[N];
sprintf(&buf[0], "%d ", i);
sprintf(&buf[strlen(buf)], "%f ", f);
```

etc.?

Comment: That is a very bad usage of `strlen()` specially since `sprintf()` returns the value that you need.

Comment: Partial agree with @iharob.  This is "weak" as code could be something like `size_t len = 0; int app = sprintf(&buf[len], "%d ", i); len += app; app = sprintf(&buf[len], "%f ", f); len += app; app = ...`.  Disagree it is "bad".

Comment: @iharob - point taken and agreed, this was an "air code", just to exemplify the point.

Answer (score 0):

You can always override the default `printf()` by implementing it and excluding `stdio.h` which would make things very hard.

Another solution is to write a macro like

```
#define printf(...) override_printf(__VA_ARGS__)
```

the hard part is implementing `override_printf()` properly, but it's a lot easier than the previous solution, now if you can use the *glibc* specific<sup>1</sup> [`open_memstream()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html), then this solution is quite simple

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define printf(...) fprintf(stream, __VA_ARGS__)

int main(void)
{
    FILE  *stream;
    char  *content;
    size_t length;

    length = 0;
    stream = open_memstream(&content, &length);
    if (stream == NULL)
        return -1;
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    printf("Just writing some text\n");
    /* Don't forget to `fclose()` the stream before using the poitner */
    fclose(stream);
    fprintf(stdout, "size: %zu\ncontent:\n%s\n", length, content);
    free(content);

    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>The manual page claims that it might be available on other systems, it's not widely available though.